# Designing The ListView in DrawerLayout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-listview, drawerlayout

I have a DrawerLayout and its working well. I'd like to have this design the one highlighted by orange. The selected item on the ListView will have this background effect. What are good approaches to attain this one. Is it a background image or is a transparent image that covers the `item`? Thanks

I also found this [tutorial](http://www.michenux.net/android-listview-highlight-selected-item-387.html). The purpose of my post is to find good resolve on this.

[image]

Not sure how to do this on my xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </FrameLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#111"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Override `ListView` and draw the arrow in the `dispatchDraw()` method.

Comment: @Luksprog  thanks for the hint. I found a tut about a `TransparentPanel` is that what you referring to? hmmm. when you say `draw the arrow` am I going to put a drawable or just pure piant?

Comment: You can draw an image or make the arrow yourself or whatever. I wasn't referring to a `TransparentPanel`(I don't know what is that), I was simply referring at drawing that arrow based on the position of the current checked item of the `ListView`.

Comment: great point, hhmm, I'll try, handling this one programmatically if I fail then I have to use xml and maximize the use of `View states`. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

A transparent background for the listView and a png image with the desired effect for the list item will do it for you. e.g :

```
     <ListView
       android:id="@+id/list"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:background="@null" />
```

and then the layout for your list_item should have a png with the desired effect as background. e.g:

```
    <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/list_item_parent_layout"
      android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
      android:layout_width ="wrap_content"
      android:background ="@drawable/desired_png" >

      <!-- place what ever views you want  --> 

   </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Just to clarify sir you want me to use custom array adapter and use `getView()` to populate an xml view to the listView? Can you show how you handle this programmatically sir? Thanks

Comment: offcourse you will have to use a custom array adapter. I am editing my answer to show a custom arrayadapter. see the updated one after a while.

Comment: ok i found a tutorial on how to use a custom adapter with listview. have a look at this link : http://learnandroideasily.blogspot.com/2013/06/listview-with-custom-adapter.html